# Ranking without duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, point

Below is the replica of my code, my main goal is to get the rank of certain images based on its photo_id. The code below is working perfectly fine, but the problem is, if there are ties total points, those two images gets the same rank number.  What I really want is, if these images has the same total points, I want to rank them by date. How can I accomplish this?

```
SELECT  uo.*, 
    ( SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ui.total_points)
    FROM    photo_list ui
            WHERE   ui.total_points>= uo.total_points
            ) AS rank
    FROM    photo_list uo
    WHERE photo_id = :photo_id
```

Here is what my table looks like:

```
id  | photo_id | total_points | date
1      432cfc        0          1403076412
2      fsd324        1          1403076413
3      gd43ds        0          1403076411
```

Here is my desire results:

```
   rank  | photo_id | total_points | date
    1      fsd324        1          1403076413
    2      gd43ds        0          1403076411
    3      432cfc        0          1403076412
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY total_points , date`.This should work.

Comment: It doesn't give it a try

Comment: can you provide sample data and DDL ??

Comment: Specify data-structure of your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    SELECT  uo.*, 
    (SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ui.total_points)
    FROM    photo_list ui
    WHERE   ui.total_points>= uo.total_points
    ) AS rank
    FROM    photo_list uo
    WHERE photo_id = :photo_id
    ) as alias
order by  total_points,date;
```

Comment: you wanna sort them with points and then date right? @PimenterDgrc

Comment: schema and data please? @PimenterDgrc

Comment: @PimenterDgrc first of all this is not a code, this is the query to give you result set..you need to learn some manners, you should be helpful to the people who respond you...

Answer (score 0):

This would be the query.

```
SELECT   
    ( SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ui.total_points)
    FROM    photo_list ui
        WHERE   ui.total_points>= uo.total_points
        ) AS rank,uo.photo_id,uo.total_points,uo.date1
    FROM    photo_list uo
    ORDER BY rank ASC, date1 ASC
```

Comment: I tried with your sample data.Got result as expected.

Comment: I just tried it and it is still returning the same rank number